# Partial view - Model binding in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 models in my MVC 3 application, `CustomerOrder` and `OrderDetail`.
My Model `OrderDetai`l is with `List`.

Model

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int NetPrice { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> Orderlist { get; set; }
    public CustomerOrder()
    {
        Orderlist = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }       
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice {get{ return Price*Quantity;} }       
}
```

This is My Controller

```
public ActionResult CustomerOrder()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerOrder(CustomerOrder SelectedOrder)
{
    DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
    var result = dataBase.InsertData(SelectedOrder);
    ViewData["result"] = result;
    return View();
}
```

This is My View for `CustomerOrder`

```
@model MvcCustomerOrderClass4g.Models.CustomerOrder
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomerOrder";
}

<h2>CustomerOrder</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>CustomerOrder</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NetPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NetPrice)
        </div>    
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
@{
    if (ViewData["result"] != "" && ViewData["result"] != null)
    {       
    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
        alert("Data saved Successfully");
    </script>
    }   
}
```

My Model `OrderDetail` is with `List`. How to use it as a list in my view?
Here I want to add `OrderDetail` model. I also created another view for `OrderDetails`, for adding it as Partial in `CustomerOrder`.

Comment: What is "define the view"? What is "give in controller"?

Comment: I have given List in my model .I dont Know how to give it in the "Editorfor" field. @CodeCaster

Comment: Are you asking how do you show an editor for the `OrderList` property?

Comment: Yes How to use as a List  @James

Comment: The reason I am using List for Multiple Insertion of Orderdetails @James

Comment: @jabi you need to restructure your question to ask it correctly - otherwise I am afraid it will end up being closed.

Comment: @jabi add your `View` to the question.

Comment: I have Added the view @SOfanatic

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create an `EditorTemplate`:

```
@model OrderDetail

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)//your model doesn't seem to have an id?
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductName)
```

Then in your view with the `CustomerOrder` model just do this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderList)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderList)
```

Comment: So that works fine for a list with content, it's not going to work for an empty list (which it looks like the OP has).

Comment: I want to use this two model in One View

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(M=>M.Orderlist) THIS ONLY I AM able TO GIVE @SOfanatic

Comment: @jabi is this supposed to be a shopping cart? i.e., the customer goes in and adds products to the order (a list of products already exists in the db just need to relate those products to the customer)?

Comment: I want add Three order in a single post @SOfanatic

Comment: @jabi ok so it seems like it is a shopping cart. Basically you have a many-to-many relationship between `OrderDetails` and `CustomerOrder` with a predefined list of products that need to be "added" to a `CustomerOrder`

Comment: Ya The Products are Predefined @SOfanatic

Comment: In CustomerOrder I have given orderDetails as a List. The Problem is how to use as a List in the view @SOfanatic